# Issue in Showing Collection View in Table View Cell in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

i have a table view and i have placed a collection view inside the cell, i'm getting data from API and that data i'm passing to table view and collection view but when i run the app it crashes with this error,

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Lawon.KnowledgeVC collectionView:numberOfItemsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fa90af0cbc0

My code for table view,

```
extension KnowledgeVC : UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return categoryArray.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return categoryArray.count
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 35
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let headerView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("KnowledgeHeaderTVC", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! KnowledgeHeaderTVC

    headerView.categoryNameLbl.text = categoryArray[section].catName
    headerView.articlesLbl.text = "\(categoryArray[section].blogArray.count)" + "articles"

    return headerView
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = knowledgeTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "KnowledgeCell", for: indexPath) as! KnowledgeDetailTVC

    cell.categoryArray = categoryArray

    return cell
 }
}
```

This is my table view cell class where i have mad outlet for collection view and populating data in it and calling its delegate and datasource,

```
class KnowledgeDetailTVC: UITableViewCell,UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var categoryCollectionView : UICollectionView!
var categoryArray = [Category]()

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    self.categoryCollectionView.reloadData()
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    print(categoryArray[section].blogArray.count)
    return categoryArray[section].blogArray.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "familyCell", for: indexPath) as! FamilyCVC

    cell.categoryLbl.text = categoryArray[indexPath.section].blogArray[indexPath.row].articleTitle
    let imageUrl = categoryArray[indexPath.section].blogArray[indexPath.row].imageUrl!
    print(imageUrl)
    cell.categoryImage.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: imageUrl), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "person.jpeg"))
    //            cell.bgView.layer.masksToBounds = true
    //            cell.bgView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    //            cell.bgView.layer.shadowOpacity = 3
    //            cell.bgView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: -1, height: 1)
    //            cell.bgView.layer.shadowRadius = 2
    //            cell.bgView.layer.shouldRasterize = true

    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may set the delegate & dataSource of the collectionView in the prototype cell to the `KnowledgeVC`  in IB while implementation is inside the cell , but you should set them in `awakeFromNib`

```
self.categoryCollectionView.delegate = self
self.categoryCollectionView.dataSource = self
self.categoryCollectionView.reloadData()
```

---

Also it's better to refresh it inside `cellForRowAt` to avoid dequeuing problems

```
cell.categoryArray = categoryArray
cell.categoryCollectionView.reloadData()
```

> There is no compile time error thrown in that case and that is a big problem of setting the delegate and dataSource in IB

Comment: I have made IBOutlet in table view cell class for collection view and call its delegate and datasource in table view cell class as mention in code. @Sh_Khan

Comment: Do you still have the problem after following the answer ? Also don't you have a prototype table cell inside the vc that contains the collection ?

Comment: how to make IBOutlet of collection view in knowledge VC, will collection view is placed inside the cell of table view? Its showing me error. @Sh_Khan

Comment: outlet should be inside the cell anyway , you need to copy all delegate and dataSource methods of the collection to the vc and assign the delegate and dataSource of the collectionView to the vc inside `cellForRowAt` or leave it as it's now assigned when you posted the question